# Run JPA using Maven and Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: maven, jpa, intellij-idea, eclipselink

I have just switch over to Intellij IDEA and I am trying to test my JPA entities using a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit. My environment is currently using EclipseLink, MySQL and Maven.

At the moment my test class is performing the following call:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("app-test");
```

The persistence unit is being detected (if I change the name in the persistence.xml file, I get an error saying the unit cannot be found). However, if I run the test I am getting the following errors in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1005354a
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [app-test] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:115)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at suite.Suite.main(Suite.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [app-test] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1541)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:105)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [app-test] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.hasEntity(MetadataProject.java:1272)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.objects.MetadataAnnotatedElement.isOneToMany(MetadataAnnotatedElement.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.buildAccessor(ClassAccessor.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessorFields(ClassAccessor.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.preProcess(ClassAccessor.java:1178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.MappedSuperclassAccessor.preProcess(MappedSuperclassAccessor.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.preProcess(EntityAccessor.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage1(MetadataProject.java:1649)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1469)
    ... 10 more
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="app-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.app.entities</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-entities</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>app-entities</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My folder structure (all my entities are in the src/main/java folder):

[image]

Comment: Apart from the fact that you left out the `<repositories>` section of your POM, your setup works for me in both IntelliJ 11 and Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: I've tried it with the repositories section included, but it also does't work. How are you running it Intellij?

Comment: Sorry my last comment didn't make much sense. How do you run the application within IntelliJ? Do you run the application using the green arrow at the top or are you using the maven section to the right?

Comment: Either should work. I ran the particular test class using the (right click) context sensitive menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the project and recreated it from scratch and it is working now.